# Precipitation and weather and seasons on other planets

Tags: planet, rotation, temperature

I have participated in an exhibition on astronomy and decided to make a project on the topic "weather season and precipitation on other planets"

I have the knowledge about the weather on earth but I need to know more about that on other planets in the solar system like venus, mars, mercury and Jupiter etc or in other planets in the other galaxies.

Can anyone explain me how the precipitation and season  occurs,why do it occur, what is the effect,do they form clouds or something else,how do the temperature rotation and revolution affect the process? You can also suggest me some videos on this topic

Thanks in advance

Comment: For information, a few years ago this interesting paper came out: [How often does it Rain on Titan?](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2012/pdf/2472.pdf). Quite short but it includes a few interesting references which you may be able to find through your library.

Comment: its superb advance

Comment: As a tip, I wouldn't even talk about other galaxies.   The variation between galaxies might not be all that much as there appears to be quite a bit of similarity throughout the universe.   It's mostly just hydrogen, dark matter and supermassive black holes, after which there's, mixing, fusion and time so one galaxy might be a lot like another.    I'd stick with the milky way and even, the local part of the Milky way where some planets have been observed.  No need to push it outside the galaxy.